# Errno 24: Too many open files. But I am not opening files?

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted

I am using treq (https://github.com/twisted/treq) to query some other api from my web service. Today when I was doing stress testing of my own services, It shows an error

`twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: address 'api.abc.com' not found: [Errno 24] Too many open files.`

But the problem is, my entire code I didn't open any file. I suspect it could be caused by the api I query goes down or blocked me (the api.abc.com) since my stress testing could be like a ddos to that end point. Still, in that case shouldn't that be something like refuse connection? I don't know why it will have that `Too many open files` error. Or is that caused by creating too much thread query?

Comment: "files" really means file descriptors and includes things like sockets, so if you're opening a lot of connections you could run into this problem still

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"Files" include network sockets, which are a type of file on Unix-based systems.  The maximum number of open files is configurable with `ulimit -n`, and the limit is inherited by child processes:

```
# Check current limit
$ ulimit -n
256

# Raise limit to 2048
# Only affects processes started from this shell
$ ulimit -n 2048

$ ulimit -n
2048
```

It is not surprising to run out of file handles and have to raise the limit.  But if the limit is already high, you may be leaking file handles (not closing them quickly enough).  In garbage-collected languages like Python, the finalizer does not always close files fast enough, which is why you should be careful to use `with` blocks or other systems to close the files as soon as you are done with them.

Comment: Looks like this `ulimit` is specific to a particular terminal. Is it? My `ulimit` is 1024. I set it to 5000 in a terminal but its still showing 1024 in all other terminals except the terminal in which I set it to 5000.

Comment: @phanny: Resource limits are inherited from the parent process.

Comment: Can Dietrich's comment be added to the answer please?

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to build on @Dietrich Epp answer. Setting ulimit -n will change the current limit for that terminal only. If you would like to change this limit so it exists across all terminal sessions (such as on EC2), you need to edit:

`vim /etc/security/limits.conf`

and add soft and hard limits for the number of open descriptors per user. As an example, you can paste this snippet in the file above:

```
*         hard    nofile      500000
*         soft    nofile      500000
root      hard    nofile      500000
root      soft    nofile      500000
```

This will set the limit to 500000 with every new terminal session. After editing, sign out and then back in, (or reboot if you are able and that's preferable). Afterwards, you can run `ulimit -n` to confirm that it's been set properly.

Comment: why the default value being so low? Is there any drawback to set a high value to ulimit?

Comment: @ddzzbbwwmm Honestly it just really depends on what your application is. Some applications rely on a high number of open connections in order to accomplish their task while the majority of tasks are fine under the default. The drawback to setting a high value to ulimit would be it covering up issues that could have been caught otherwise, such as a rogue processes that are using a lot of resources. It acts as a type of safeguard. As long as you understand your application and can monitor things, it can be a useful setting.