# Airflow task: OSError: [Errno 23] Too many open files in system

Tags: ubuntu, airflow

Does anyone has had this error with the S3PrefixSensor?

`OSError: [Errno 23] Too many open files in system: '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json'`

I'm having that error when the scheduler runs over 12 tasks with that operator at the same time.  If I rerun them manually, they work fine.

I tried increasing the ulimit as suggested by the answer of this question but it didn't work for me: [Errno 24: Too many open files. But I am not opening files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537731/errno-24-too-many-open-files-but-i-am-not-opening-files)

It's odd that error is coming up, as I'm only running 12 tasks at the same time. Is it an issue with the S3 sensor operator?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lsof | grep -c endpoints.json` and  `ulimit -a | grep 'open files'`

Comment: @lllrnr101 The output of the first command is 0 and the 2nd command is  ```open files                      (-n) 500240```

Comment: Damn! Then I will bookmark the question to see how you finally solved it. I would also keep an eye on `lsof | grep -c <PID>` after starting the program.

Comment: Are you importing the sensor from `airflow.sensors.s3_prefix_sensor.S3PrefixSensor` ?

Comment: @Elad yes, I am.

Comment: Removing the bookmark!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned in comments that you use `airflow.sensors.s3_prefix_sensor.S3PrefixSensor`
This is an outdated version of the sensor.

The updated version contains [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/7541) which caches the hook and prevent creating a new connection every time the sensor poke.

For `Airflow<2.0.0` install [backport provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-backport-providers-amazon
```

For `Airflow>=2.0.0` install [providers](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/):

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon
```

Then import the sensor via:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3_prefix import S3PrefixSensor
```