Pytest fails: Too many open files
I have faced a very strange issue:
when I run our python test-cases with pytest, it starts to fails with the log below stating that too many files are open.
I have googled around, but haven't found any solution and don't have any glue what causes this behavioral
Can anybody help me (even if you need further information, please let me know).
pytest -vvvv --setup-show tests
=========================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-8.3.2, pluggy-1.5.0 -- <path>/.env/bin/python3
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: <path>
plugins: cov-5.0.0
collected 135 items / 3 errors                                                                                                                                                                            

================================================================================================= ERRORS ==================================================================================================
________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/functional/test_user_functional.py ________________________________________________________________________
/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1014: in _gcd_import
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:991: in _find_and_load
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:975: in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ???
<frozen importlib._bootstrap>:671: in _load_unlocked
    ???
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:165: in exec_module
    source_stat, co = _rewrite_test(fn, self.config)
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py:343: in _rewrite_test
    source = fn.read_bytes()
/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py:1229: in read_bytes
    ???
/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py:1222: in open
    ???
/usr/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py:1078: in _opener
    ???
E   OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '<path>/functional/test_user_functional.py'
____________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_data _____________________________________________________________________________________
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:341: in from_call
    result: TResult | None = func()
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:389: in collect
    return list(collector.collect())
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py:523: in collect
    for direntry in scandir(self.path):
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py:885: in scandir
    with os.scandir(path) as s:
E   OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '<path>/test_data'
_______________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting tests/unit _______________________________________________________________________________________
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:341: in from_call
    result: TResult | None = func()
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py:389: in collect
    return list(collector.collect())
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/main.py:523: in collect
    for direntry in scandir(self.path):
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_pytest/pathlib.py:885: in scandir
    with os.scandir(path) as s:
E   OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '<path>/unit'
============================================================================================ warnings summary =============================================================================================
.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_fields.py:201
  <path>/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_fields.py:201: UserWarning: Field name "schema" in "SnowflakeConnectModel" shadows an attribute in parent "BaseModel"

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/how-to/capture-warnings.html
========================================================================================= short test summary info =========================================================================================
ERROR tests/functional/test_user_functional.py - OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '<path>/functional/test_user_functional.py'
ERROR tests/test_data - OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '<path>/test_data'
ERROR tests/unit - OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '<path>/unit'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 3 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
====================================================================================== 1 warning, 3 errors in 3.06s =======================================================================================


ulimit output:
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 29053
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 29053
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39537731/errno-24-too-many-open-files-but-i-am-not-opening-files

It's hard to say where exactly is the problem, you need to make sure you close all the connections you open (for example session = requests.Session() session.close() or simply with requests.Session() as s:).

see if any of the following help : drop into the shell ; try lsof -u $USER | wc -l;  cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max, ls /proc/{PID}/fd | wc -l where {PID} is the 'offending' process id

posting a pertinent code snippet may also help folks give feedback.
