# Python Popen: "OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files" Mojave

Tags: python, macos, popen, macos-mojave

I'm running a third party library called Pydub on macOS Mojave, I'm trying to process >100k MP3 tracks, using Pydub for IO, so this function is called a lot. The offending function in Pydub is below. I've tried to modify it by putting `Popen` in a `with` statement as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57756906/9035662), but I still get an error. I know that I could probably solve this problem by increasing `ulimit`, but this seems like the wrong approach?

Is there anything wrong with this code?

```py
def mediainfo_json(filepath):
    """Return json dictionary with media info(codec, duration, size, bitrate...) from filepath
    """
    prober = get_prober_name()
    command_args = [
        "-v", "info",
        "-show_format",
        "-show_streams",
    ]
    try:
        command_args += [fsdecode(filepath)]
        stdin_parameter = None
        stdin_data = None
    except TypeError:
        command_args += ["-"]
        stdin_parameter = PIPE
        file = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(filepath, 'rb', tempfile=False)
        file.seek(0)
        stdin_data = file.read()

    command = [prober, '-of', 'json'] + command_args
    with Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as res:
        output, stderr = res.communicate(input=stdin_data)
        output = output.decode("utf-8", 'ignore')
        stderr = stderr.decode("utf-8", 'ignore')

    info = json.loads(output)

    if not info:
        # If ffprobe didn't give any information, just return it
        # (for example, because the file doesn't exist)
        return info

    extra_info = get_extra_info(stderr)

    audio_streams = [x for x in info['streams'] if x['codec_type'] == 'audio']
    if len(audio_streams) == 0:
        return info

    # We just operate on the first audio stream in case there are more
    stream = audio_streams[0]
```

This is the relevant portion of the stack trace:

```py
/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/dl/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pydub/utils.py in mediainfo_json(filepath)
    261 
    262     command = [prober, '-of', 'json'] + command_args
--> 263     with Popen(command, stdin=stdin_parameter, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as res:
    264         output, stderr = res.communicate(input=stdin_data)
    265         output = output.decode("utf-8", 'ignore')

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/dl/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
    773                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    774                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    776         except:
    777             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/dl/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1410             # Data format: "exception name:hex errno:description"
   1411             # Pickle is not used; it is complex and involves memory allocation.
-> 1412             errpipe_read, errpipe_write = os.pipe()
   1413             # errpipe_write must not be in the standard io 0, 1, or 2 fd range.
   1414             low_fds_to_close = []

OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you close ````file````. How often do you fall into that exception block?

Comment: I added a `file.close()` and I still get the same error. I can't be sure exactly how many calls it takes to get the exception, but to give an idea, with 12 threads running concurrently, it takes about 2 minutes of repeated calls before it stops.